# How to build standalone python installation

Tags: python

How can I build python interpreter which can be installed by just extracting the archive?

e.g. I want to python-2.6.tar.gz. User will extract it in any directory, and start using it.

Comment: The interpreter is easy. The hard part is the stdlib.

Comment: and you meant .tar.gz, right?

Comment: Since most Linux distributions include Python nowadays doing this on Linux would be silly. ;)

Comment: Python has been included in Mac OS X as well for many years, now.

Comment: @Christopher looking for platform independent scripts which can build standalone python. Primarily looking for linux, solaris, hpux, aix. Have found few options for windows, but would like to get same scripts working for windows also. (Basic assumption: I have required compiler for the given platform).

Yes, .tar.gz can be one way. Or it can be .zip or .rar or any other supported archive+compression format.

Comment: @Lennart, I haven't found python installation on solaris, windows, aix, hpux by default. No python 2.6.x on aix...:(. Having custom installation makes sure you have the correct version of python, along with the required libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [`portablepython`](http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/Download) (currently Windows only) will help. You can try using it directly, or follow the install process to learn how to create such an environment.

> Portable Python is a  Python® programming language preconfigured to run directly from any USB storage device, enabling you to have, at any time, a portable programming environment.

Comment: Let me second this. I was able to convince people about using Python in my former job (a management consulting firm) by loading Portable Python and a bunch of well designed scripts in a USB. They would say 'Oh, Excel cannot do such and such!' and I would come, plug in my USB on their computer, solve the problem, write a data file (in CSV for Excel to use), unplug the USB, and finally pull out my sword and crave a big "P" on their chests. The last step is a lie, but the others are not.

Comment: Portable python looks nice. Didn't find anything which can help to build it on other platforms though.

Answer (score 1):

I went another way, on debian, and wrote a script to automate the install of python.

This is python-specific, but uses fabric and paramiko to deploy python on remote machines. see:

http://bitbucket.org/chris.mahan/debian-stable-python-2.6.4-deployer/

This may help you.